# play music to caller while simultaneous dial to multiple destinations

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twimlet

We've got a basic twiml set up that sends a call to multiple destinations, it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play loop="10">https://xxx.xxx.xxx/assets/MoH.wav</Play>
    <Dial>
        <Number>+1800XXXXXXX</Number>
        <Number>+1912XXXXXXX</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The problem with this is that the `<Dial>` doesn't happen until the `<Play>` finishes. We want to play music to the caller while waiting for the call to be answered by one of the destination parties.

We've tried `<Enqueue>` to play the music but it still doesn't dial simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are right that TwiML expects to finish one verb before it starts the next, so in your example code it will play the `<Play>` all the way through before starting to dial the numbers.

If you want to play music to the caller while the dial happens, then you will need to use [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) to put them into a holding pattern while you dial the other numbers. However, you will not be able to use TwiML to dial the numbers, instead you will need to [make the outbound calls using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls).

Once one of the outbound calls connects, you can then connect it with the original call by [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial)ling in to the [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/queue) that you placed the caller in. You will also want to [end the other calls using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-resource-to-end-the-call&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x).